# Difference between 3d projection matrix found in wiki and the glm's matrixx

Tags: math, linear-algebra, glm-math, projection-matrix

So, I found [This(3d projection matrix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Mathematical_formula) in wikipedia, and I am curious about the difference between it and the approach in glm(glm::perspective * glm::lookat). Also I have seen people use the way in the wikipedia to optain the "front" and "right" vector that is use in the glm::perspective and the glm::lookAt from the pitch and yaw. Will this cause any error in the two vector if I use them in glm?